# Why does the filter method on an array that returns no results not give an empty array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, methods

I am trying to use a conditional with the filter method on an array in Javascript. The issue I am having is that comparing an empty array to a filtered array that should be empty because the filter returns no results and should return an empty array according to [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is not achieving the results desired.

I have tried creating empty arrays in a Node.js session in the terminal and also in the test environment on https://www.codewars.com .

// node environment on my terminal

```
const emptyArr = []

const arr2 = [1, 1, 2, 2]

const testArr = arr2.filter((iso) => iso >= 3)

testArr === emptyArr //prints false, but should be true
```

The expected result should be true, because according to MDN an empty filter returns an empty array. The actual result, however, is false meaning that the filtered array is not actually empty.

Comment: In javascript arrays are objects and comparison of two objects will always return `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a post that answers this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38548366/4447481

> `[] === []` is `false` because they're two *different* empty arrays.

You'll want to compare the contents of two arrays to determine equality.

In your case, you may want to check length, like this:

```
if(!arr1.length && !arr2.length) {
    /* do something */
}
```

Comment: You should vote to close the question as duplicate rather than giving your own answer.

Comment: I don't know how. :-(